# App is force closing when a Button is clicked inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I just started converting my Activities to Fragments, just finished converting an Activity and found out that when I click on a Button in that Fragment the app is force closing!

This is my Activity class: Attendence

```
package wonderkids.wonderkids;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



import static wonderkids.wonderkids.R.layout.exam;

public class Attendence extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(exam);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    Intent browserIntent;

    public void one(View v) {
        Button clickedButton = (Button) v;
        switch (clickedButton.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;
            case R.id.button2:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button3:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button4:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button5:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button6:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button7:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button8:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button9:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button10:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            /*case R.id.fab:{
                Intent i = new Intent(Exams.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            }*/
        }
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}
```

This is the fragment which should replace Attendence

Attendance.java

```
package wonderkids.wonderkids;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import static wonderkids.wonderkids.R.layout.exam;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Attendance extends Fragment {


    public Attendance() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.exam, container,false);
    }
    Intent browserIntent;

    public void one(View v) {
        Button clickedButton = (Button) v;
        switch (clickedButton.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;
            case R.id.button2:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button3:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button4:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button5:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button6:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button7:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button8:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button9:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}
            case R.id.button10:{
                browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                break;}

        }
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}
```

This is the main class which switches Fragments:
Check onNavigationItemSelected...

```
package wonderkids.wonderkids;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private static final String LOG_TAG =
            Home.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.start);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"In Create");
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"In Create");
    }

    public void gall1(View view){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Gallery.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    public void hw1(View view){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Hworks.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    public void con1(View view){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Contact.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    public void res1(View view){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Results.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    public void sta1(View view){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Staff.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    public void bus1(View view){
        Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    public void exa1(View view){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Exams.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    public void att1(View view){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Attendence.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(id==R.id.action_exit) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gal1ery) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, Gallery.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_exams) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, Exams.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_attendence) {
            fragment = new Attendance();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_results) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, Results.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            try {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Wonder Kids");
                String sAux = "\nTry This\n";
                sAux = sAux + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Orion.Soft \n\n";
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "choose one"));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                //e.toString();
            }
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cotact) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, Contact.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_newsletter) {
            Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;


    }
}
```

And this is the xml file for Attendance (Fragment) which I also used for Attendence(Activity) and many other... (Buttons work fine when accessing exam.xml from another Activity)

exam.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    tools:context="wonderkids.wonderkids.Attendance">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:onClick="one"
        android:text="1st class"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
        android:onClick="one"
        android:text="3rd class"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:onClick="one"
        android:text="4th class"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:onClick="one"
        android:text="6th class"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:onClick="one"
        android:text="2nd class"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:onClick="one"
        android:text="5th class"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:onClick="one"
        android:text="7th class"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:onClick="one"
        android:text="8th class"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:onClick="one"
        android:text="9th class"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:onClick="one"
        android:text="10th class"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button8"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And if needed this is the empty container:

startac.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="wonderkids.wonderkids">



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/spl"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/spl"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Home" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".Exams"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".Results"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".Contact"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".Attendence"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".Hworks"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".Staff"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="WonderKids"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Gallery"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gallery"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my crash report:

```
04-23 02:46:20.797 15458-15458/wonderkids.wonderkids E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: wonderkids.wonderkids, PID: 15458
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method one(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button8'
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
04-23 02:46:20.828 534-1480/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity wonderkids.wonderkids/.Home
```

And when I see Attendance(fragment) near

```
import static wonderkids.wonderkids.R.layout.exam;
```

and

`one` in     `public void one(View v) {`

I get unused import statement and method one is never used!
If u need any extra code or didn't understand my question please comment!

Comment: What about stacktrace?

Comment: Have you registered the opening activity on Manifest.xml?

Comment: @statosdotcom yess Ive added .home activity in mainfest.xml

Comment: Exclude this `import static wonderkids.wonderkids.R.layout.exam;` from before your class.

Comment: @statosdotcom the app still force closes!!

Comment: Please, try to make your app run and when it closes don't close it: see at the left lower of Android Studio, there is a button "Android Monitor", there you will find your logcat. See if there are additional info about the error you're finding. The problematic line of your code may be pointed there. Have a see. Maybe edit your post here to show us this "stacktrace", as the first commenter asked you.

Comment: @azizbekian posted stack trace

Comment: @statosdotcom Once can check my manifest file..Thank You and also posted stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement `one(View v)` in `Home` class if you are trying to use the XML `android:onClick` like that.

If you want the Fragment to handle the click, then use something like this

```
public class Attendance extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public Attendance() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exam, container,false);

        // Set click listneer
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.button8).setOnClickListener(Attendance.this);

        return rootView;
    }
    Intent browserIntent;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                url = "https://www.google.com";
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                url = "https://www.google.com";
                break;
        }
        browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: You're the guy. Thank you.

Comment: @statosdotcom Alternatively, I suggest creating a single OnClickListener for each button. You can do this fairly easily with anonymous inner classes or lambdas. Personally, I dislike a single `onClick()` method with a long switch statement for all of my buttons.

Comment: Seriously ThankYou :)

Comment: @Code-App I was told that individual anonymous classes makes the compiled app size larger

Comment: @cricket_007 That might be true. Would be interesting to measure how much of an increase it is. Still, I'll take the increased app size over less readable and less maintainable code.

Comment: getting this error
setOnClickListener(android.view.View.onClickListener) in view can not be applied to (wonderkids.wonderkids.Attendance)

Comment: @Code-App switch case could still delegate to separate methods. Personally, this is one of those points I'd prefer to have Function objects mapped to resource ids

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I think you was talking (above comment) with operator, yes? Anyway, nice contribution. I'm learning here too. Thank you.

Comment: @Bharath You're calling the method on an Attendance object, not a View

Comment: @Bharath See... `implements View.OnClickListener`?? You missed it

Comment: @cricket_007 In the code you answered above 
rootView.findViewById(R.id.button8).setOnClickListener(this);
in this line this is underlined red... when I point mouse on it it showed
setOnClickListener(android.view.View.onClickListener) in view can not be applied to (wonderkids.wonderkids.Attendance)

Comment: @BharathAtmakuri Be sure to put `public class Attendance extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener`.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes .. :(

Comment: @statosdotcom My bad. I thought you were the OP. (p.s. OP stands for "Original Poster")

Comment: @BharathAtmakuri Be sure to read my first comment. I accidentally pinged someone else.

Comment: Well, if you are implementing the interface, that error does not make sense to me

Comment: getting this error Class 'Attendance' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in 'OnClickListener'
So I removed implements View.OnClickListener

Comment: @Bharath Why?  If you **follow those directions**, you **must** implement `onClick(View)` as shown in my answer ;)

Comment: can I set onClickListeners to all buttons at once??

Comment: At once? Not quite... Even in the XML, you assigned them individually. You can simply set them all to the same listener

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Remove `import static wonderkids.wonderkids.R.layout.exam;` from your Atandance fragment.

**2.** Remove `tools:context="wonderkids.wonderkids.Attendance"` from your `exam.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back">

    .....................
    ...................................
</<FrameLayout
```

`Clean`, `Build` and `Run` your application again.

Hope this will work~

Comment: `tools:context` doesn't do anything special, though

Comment: no removing those and performing clean build run didn't work